# Automated EXCEL line chart updating using new inserted data

Tags: excel, vba, plot, automation

Suppose that I have some date in EXCEL. I need my line plot automatically updated after adding new data. We can Have more(or less) rows (x1,x2, etc.) or more or less columns (years) or both. I want EXCEL automatically update chart by using new inserted data (we don't know new row and column size). How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: tables are the best bet.

Comment: @cyboashu. How can I do that?

Comment: @Mat'sMug. Currently I'm checking some VBA codes.

Comment: will post an answer in few mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

First you need [to convert it to table.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664)

[image]

After that yiu are all set, now insert a chart based on this table.

After that, whenever you edit/update your table, the change will be reflected realtime in your chart.

Its that simple.:)